# How do I copy an object's position (or other transform), and paste it to another object?

Tags: object-mode

How do I copy the location of an object and paste it into another object?

I could copy the x/y/z etc one at a time but this is very laborious.

This seemed to be a simple question, but I couldn't find anything on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the object you want to copy the location from then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected* then select the object(s) you want to move and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*:

[image]

Or select the object(s) that you want to move, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the one with the good location, right click on the location values > *Copy All to Selected*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about this question, but just noticed it's a "Popular Question" so I accepted your answer. Josh's answer was good too, I didn't upvote it because it involved an addon. For a popular question though, I'm amazed you don't have more upvotes.

Comment: It may be already answered somewhere in Blender Stack Exchange  ;)

Comment: Probably is, but searching for it gave no hits when I first asked this (which may be me), so my guess is the search algorithms are dumping more people here.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to theese responses, I recommend this useful built in addon: "Animation: Copy Global Transform", which is very fast and useful, expecially during animation, as it takes into account constraints also, with a simple Copy/paste operation.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/addons/animation/copy_global_transform.html

Answer (score 1):

Most searches will show you how to copy an armature / bone location.

There is an add on, that's 'built-in' but not activated that makes the process simple.

Go to Edit->Preferences, then Add-ons, then search for "attrib".

Enable the Interface: Copy Attributes Menu.

The interface is a tad strange if you're used to "object/verb". You select both objects - the 'first' one is the one that'll move, oddly - then type Ctrl+c then choose what transforms you want pasted.

It's not 'copy and paste' it's select the items then copy the location from active (last selected) element to all others selected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @josh